# Source for regularly updated ENCs?

Tags: data, chart

Is there a reliable source for Electronic Navigation Charts, where they get updated regularly? I am able to find for American waters on the NOAA website, but not for other regions.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I am not looking for open data specifically. Even some proprietary (paid) source should work, provided it is reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple I was able to source. Listed in order of relevancy/trustworthiness.

http://ris.vlaanderen.be/html_en/vaarkaarten/index.html -Belgian government ENCs

http://ienccloud.us -inland USA ENCs, from the Army Geospatial center

https://www.aragon-technologies.com/en/starnavpilot/download_free_nautical_charts.php -Aragon Technologies has compiled a large list, especially for European waters

http://www.opennauticalchart.org -literally a world ENC online map. Downloadable in a variety of formats.

Less reliable:

https://sites.google.com/site/nauticalfree/ -user compiled but seems to be thorough

https://sourceforge.net/projects/opennautical/ -sourceforge open source ENC downloads

Answer (score 1):

For a non-open data option, I work at [UKHO](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-hydrographic-office), who publish over [15000 ENCs](https://www.admiralty.co.uk/digital-services/digital-charts/admiralty-vector-chart-service) and coverage is fully global. I believe UKHO are one of the only hydrographic offices that maintain global coverage. As you say, most countries will chart their own territorial waters only.

Updates are applied continuously and pushed out to users - I believe that you can download weekly updates (or receive them on disc).

In terms of accuracy, all the data are official and meet the requirements of the IHO standard for navigation data.

To buy ENCs, details of distributor near you can be found [here](https://www.admiralty.co.uk/how-to-buy).

Comment: Thanks; what might be the best way to purchase and access online for a Singapore/ India based company?

Comment: I've edited to add a link to the distributors - it looks like there are 10+ in India and 10+ Singapore so one of those would be your best contact!